Moving row script to trigger on past dates not working
I have a script that moves a row when the date in the row is equal todays date.
The script has timebased trigger and watches 3 tabs in my sheet called: Återkomster, Bokad, Resting. When it finds rows with a date that is equal todays date it will then move the row to my main tab called: Pipe.
It has worked before and I didn't do any changes in the script and I can't get it to work now for some reason, when I try to run it in the script editor I get this error "ReferenceError: isValidDate is not defined"
One other thing I tried to fix when it did work was that I also want it to move the row to the main tab starting from the second column.
I have sample sheet here with the script in it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Vkd8_T4uzzS18E6VfA332YLfen-G5Oe0g_L5xiKsmk/edit?usp=sharing
Any ideas and suggestions here would be very appreciated.
Here is the script:
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSh = ss.getSheetByName("Pipe");
  var sheets = ["Återkomster","Bokad","Resting"], sourceSh,dateCell;
  var dateCol = [];
  dateCol["Återkomster"] = 14;
  dateCol["Bokad"] = 15;
  dateCol["Resting"] = 20; 
  for (var sheetName of sheets)
  {
    sourceSh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheetData = sourceSh.getDataRange().getValues();

    // Check all values from your "Flight Schedule" sheet
    for(i = sheetData.length-1; i>= 0; i--){
      // Check if the value is a valid date
      dateCell = sheetData[i][dateCol[sheetName]-1];
      if(isValidDate(dateCell)){
        const today = new Date();
        const test = new Date(dateCell);
        // If the value is a valid date and is a past date, we remove it from the sheet to paste on the other sheet
        if(test == today){
          
          targetSh.appendRow(sheetData[i]);
          targetSh.getRange(targetSh.getLastRow(),1).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
          sourceSh.deleteRow(i+1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}´´´´



I tried to define the range in the datecols with getrange to see if that solves the problem since the error wanted me to define the range. When I tried to run it in the script editor nothing happend


There MUST be a function called isValidDate(d). Possibly you deleted it accidentally. Have a look here for the original. function isValidDate(d) {   if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]" )     return false;   return !isNaN(d.getTime()); }

Thanks @Tedinoz that worked. I didn't release that it was a function that it needed to call in order to get it working. I had that before and yes I must have deleted that one.

Now I just need to paste in the next available row in the second column

Now I just need to paste in the next available row in the second column There's a general rule of one question = one problem. Since the inValidDate issue was basically a coding error/red herring, may I respectfully suggest that you delete your answer (you already made a good comment) and allow users to focus on the "next available row in the second column" issue.

The question has been answered at Moving script dosen't get last row in Col B. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

@Tedinoz - That was the issue with my script, the function was missing here.
function isValidDate(d) {
  if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]" )
    return false;
  return !isNaN(d.getTime());
}

